# If I exclude all 64-bit libraries from my android app, will it run entirely in a 32-bit mode?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building my Android app excluding all ARM v7 and ARM64 v8 libraries, per this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799825/736963 (though I include only `armeabi` in the ARM family.) This is because I have a 3rd-party library that is only built to the `armeabi` target. This scheme is working as expected, but I'm left with this nagging doubt...

Under this scheme, does that mean that if I run the app on 64-bit device that *everything* running in my app is running in a 32-bit mode? In other words, all the android/java code included in the app that ultimately reaches through to backing libraries, is it running the ARMv5 versions of the Android SDK (e.g., display routines, math routines, etc.)? Or do the calls to the Android SDK operate on platform-native code even if the *included* binaries (the `.so`'s) are all ARMv5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the APK installer chooses to install 32 bit binaries (from an `armeabi` or `armeabi-v7a` directory), the whole process, including all platform libraries within your process, will run in 32 bit mode.

This is not quite as dramatic and bad as you think though. All the platform libraries will have been built with the maximum amount of optimizations for your current device, even in 32 bit mode. So even if your app contains binaries in `armeabi` mode, the platform's libraries aren't restricted to the limitations of that baseline; they will use whatever best instructions available on your particular device. The only downside is that it uses the slightly less efficient 32 bit mode, but the actual difference and effect is mostly marginal.

Do note that while there is quite a big performance difference between `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`, the two are compatible in the sense that both are 32 bit; a process loading `armeabi-v7a` libraries can also load libraries in `armeabi` format just fine. (You still need to have all binaries available in all the chosen ABIs though, but that's more of an APK installer design choice.)

So in case your app only uses this third party library but no other native code of your own, you should be fine (although, depending on what the library does, you would gain some performance if the third party library supplier would provide `armeabi-v7a` or `arm64-v8a` versions). If your app has extra native code of your own, you might want to consider building it in `armeabi-v7a` mode, but copy the third party library from `armeabi` to `armeabi-v7a`. As said above, it will load and run just fine, but will allow your own code to be built with more optimizations. (Since the 32 and 64 bit versions are incompatible, you can't put the `armeabi` version into `arm64-v8a` though, as you already tried.)

The main difference between `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` is that binaries built for the latter will use hardware floating point - if you do lots of floating point calculations, it will affect performance a lot, otherwise not that much. The difference between `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` is normally not that big, for most code it's just a few percent at most.

Comment: Thanks. I stopped filtering the `armeabi-v7a` ABI and included my `so` in both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`. I built this and ran it on both a 32-bit (ARM v7) device and a 64-bit device, and everything worked. Thanks for explaining all of this! Very helpful!