# gradle project dependency with MultiDex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I have two `.aar` files that I need to add to my project as dependencies.  I imported the projects and did the following and it worked just fine.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':zoomcommonlib')
    compile project(':zoomsdk')
}
```

However, I have added many other libraries and I had to use [MultiDex library to support apps over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(':zoomcommonlib')
    compile project(':zoomsdk')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    .....
}
```

Yes, MultiDex is properly setup because I can build the application and run it with no problem.

**The problem**: When I try to utilize those specific projects, application crashes. Following Log:

```
18790-18790/com.mypackage.name E/UncaughtException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libzoom_stlport.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
       at com.zipow.cmmlib.AppContext.<clinit>(AppContext.java:31)
       at com.zipow.cmmlib.AppContext.initialize(AppContext.java:64)
       at us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK.initialize(ZoomSDK.java:225)
       at us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK.initialize(ZoomSDK.java:184)
       at com.mypackage.name.SectionListActivity.getInitializedZoomSDK(SectionListActivity.java:857)
       at com.mypackage.name.SectionListActivity.access$1500(SectionListActivity.java:88)
       at com.mypackage.name.SectionListActivity$8.onClick(SectionListActivity.java:812)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
18790-18899/com.mypackage.name D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=SectionListActivity, _si=7450316610930895524, timestamp=1488996958198, fatal=1}]
18790-18899/com.mypackage.name V/FA: Using measurement service
18790-18899/com.mypackage.name V/FA: Connecting to remote service

                                                                  --------- beginning of crash
18790-18790/com.mypackage.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.mypackage.name, PID: 18790
      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mypackage.name-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libzoom_stlport.so"
      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
      at com.zipow.cmmlib.AppContext.<clinit>(AppContext.java:31)
      at com.zipow.cmmlib.AppContext.initialize(AppContext.java:64)
      at us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK.initialize(ZoomSDK.java:225)
      at us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK.initialize(ZoomSDK.java:184)
      at com.mypackage.name.SectionListActivity.getInitializedZoomSDK(SectionListActivity.java:857)
      at com.mypackage.name.SectionListActivity.access$1500(SectionListActivity.java:88)
      at com.mypackage.name.SectionListActivity$8.onClick(SectionListActivity.java:812)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

From my understanding, those **project dependencies are not properly getting added with MultiDex enabled**. Is there some configuration that I am missing for project dependencies?

I've also tried the following in my `build.gradle` file.

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

It seems to have no effect on it. It crashes each time.

Comment: Do you have (multiDexEnabled true) under defaultConfig  in gradle https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @Tasos yes, `multiDexEnabled true` is in `defaultConfig` and ` MultiDex.install(this);` is added to `attachBaseContext()` of the `Application` class. I am able to run the app and perform many tasks. It only crashes when I call a method from those libraries

Comment: looks like dex is working but you have this error -- couldn't find "libzoom_stlport.so" -- so it looks like its missing a file

Comment: But when I remove multidex and few other dependencies, it works fine. I also created a new project with just those two dependencies and it works as well. It only stopped working after adding multidex library

Comment: i see -- well there is support here, see if you can get help from zoom https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us

Comment: @Tasos yea I tried that. Lets just say support is not their strong skill. Thanks anyway

Comment: Try to compare the contents of apk file (just unzip both multidex version and the one that working) - does *libzoom_stlport.so* present (under lib folder) in both of them?

Comment: `libzoom_stlport.so` is present in non-multidex version however it is not present in the multidex version. I did this test in a different project where multidex was not even needed (it only had three libraries. Two zoom libraries and one for multidex)

Comment: @th3pat3l Did this issue ever been solved ? And is it device specific ?

Comment: @AJay it is not device or OS specific. And no, I was not able to solve this issue.

Comment: @th3pat3l hey thanks but for me it is working on all 32 bit devices , I am facing this issue on 64 bit devices

Comment: solved, see answer

Answer (score 5):

The ZoomSDK you have doesn't support 64bit Android, unfortunately. In the mean time, you need to [disable the use of 64bit libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782848/how-to-use-32-bit-native-libaries-on-64-bit-android-device) in your app and only support the mentioned framework so it builds in 32bit mode.

Add the following to the build.gradle of the main module of your app:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

From the [Zoom forum](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/community/posts/115006896826-arm64-v8a-and-armeabi-Support):

> We support only 32 bit libs now. To work on 64 bit devices, you should
>   not use other 64 bit libs ( from other projects or other third party
>   SDK). Android OS can support 32 bit libs on 64 bit devices if you
>   don't have other 64 bit libs in the project

Comment: we need to add only   `abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"` and it solves issue for `zoom` library

Comment: does zoom sdk support 64bit devices now?

Comment: At this time, it looks like still does not because I've had to implement the same answer,

Answer (score 0):

> For x86, it can be supported via Intel ARM binary translator
>   (Houdini). But your app should not contain other x86 targeted native
>   binaries.
>
> 1. In order for the app to run on x86, all the binary files in your app should target on ARM, binary translator will translate them to
>      support x86.
> 2. If your app contains other binary files that target on x86, you should delete those files to remain only ARM targets. Because on x86
>      devices, if an app have binary files target on x86, it also should
>      have the file that target on ARM. Because Zoom Android SDK does not
>      contains any x86 binaries, so other files also can't have binaries
>      that target on x86 in order for the SDK to run.
> 3. The ARM binary translator works at run time, not at compile time.

You only need to add following to main gradle file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

and in `gradle.properties` file add the following line

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk = true
```

Comment: why `android.useDeprecatedNdk = true` works for me without

Comment: @rubenwardy cool I will also try that. And you try with only this parameters.

Comment: does zoom sdk support 64bit devices now?