# Setup ZeroMQ for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zeromq, jzmq

I am trying to use the ZMQ library in Android Studio to be able to use for an app. I've followed the ZMQ guide for Android, but still can't seem to get it to work, as I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.transend.araya.transend-E9P5bzSaIgCQBdoBpBE-4A==/lib/arm/libjzmq.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
```

I've been trying to find a solution to this for 2 days now to no avail.
Can someone provide a step by step tutorial on how I can actually start using ZMQ on my app?

Comment: You may read the first answer to see the gradle configuration 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782848/how-to-use-32-bit-native-libraries-on-64-bit-android-device

Comment: Hi @RajuyourPepe. I already have that in my gradle. I removed my 64 bit libs and now it says it can't find my so file:
                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList..../lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjzmq.so"